# Share environment variables between bash and fish

Tags: bash, environment-variables, fish

bash and fish scripts are not compatible, but I would like to have a file that defines some some environment variables to be initialized by both bash and fish.

My proposed solution is defining a `~/.env` file that would contain the list of environment variables like so:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
FOO="bar"
```

I could then just source it in bash and make a script that converts it to fish format and sources that in fish.

I was thinking that there may be a better solution than this, so I'm asking for better way of sharing environment variables between bash fish.

Note: I'm using OS X.

---

Here is an example `.env` file that I would like both fish and bash to handle using [ridiculous-fish's syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176331/9191) (assume ~/bin and ~/bin2 are empty directories):

```
setenv _PATH "$PATH"
setenv PATH "$HOME/bin"
setenv PATH "$PATH:$HOME/bin2"
setenv PATH "$PATH:$_PATH"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

bash has special syntax for setting environment variables, while fish uses a builtin. I would suggest writing your .env file like so:

```
setenv VAR1 val1
setenv VAR2 val2
```

and then defining `setenv` appropriately in the respective shells. In bash (e.g. .bashrc):

```
function setenv() { export "$1=$2"; }
. ~/.env
```

In fish (e.g. config.fish):

```
function setenv; set -gx $argv; end
source ~/.env
```

Note that PATH will require some special handling, since it's an array in fish but a colon delimited string in bash. If you prefer to write `setenv PATH "$HOME/bin:$PATH"` in .env, you could write fish's setenv like so:

```
function setenv
    if [ $argv[1] = PATH ]
        # Replace colons and spaces with newlines
        set -gx PATH (echo $argv[2] | tr ': ' \n)
    else
        set -gx $argv
    end
 end
```

This will mishandle elements in PATH that contain spaces, colons, or newlines.

The awkwardness in PATH is due to mixing up colon-delimited strings with true arrays. The preferred way to append to PATH in fish is simply `set PATH $PATH ~/bin`.

Comment: Will the `PATH` fix for fish work with paths with: spaces? newlines? other things to look out for?

Comment: `[` is a builtin in both bash and fish, so PATH should not need to be set correctly to use `[`. The setenv sample should work with all characters in PATH except for colons and newlines.

Comment: Replacing `tr` with `/usr/bin/tr` I and using the `.env` file provided in my question, I get a lot of errors when starting fish. I don't think the PATH handling is correct.

Comment: Oh, right, fish will space-separate it inside quotes. I'll update the comment.

Comment: Yay it works now. I don't think any other shell (except fish?) allows paths with colons in PATH anyway.

Comment: Why would you translate spaces to newlines there? Note that the standard `tr` syntax would be `tr ': ' '\n\n'` or `tr ': ' '[\n*]'` here. `echo -- $arg...` would be more correct, though unlikely to make much difference in practice.

Answer (score 10):

There is (now?) an easier way, per @Zanchey's answer here

[Fish Shell: How to set multiple environment variables from a file using export](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231405/fish-shell-how-to-set-multiple-environment-variables-from-a-file-using-export/231447?noredirect=1#comment395187_231447)

The digest though is:

Fish:

`echo -e "foo=3\nfoobar=4" > .env; export (cat .env);  env | grep foo`

Bash:

`echo -e "foo=3\nfoobar=4" > .env; export $(cat .env | xargs);  env | grep foo`

with the difference being `$` and the use of `xargs`

Comment: Much more convinient and without any special syntax. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't work for arrays such as $PATH

Comment: Doesn't work if you have comments in the .env file.

Answer (score 8):

Most Unix systems use [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module). The [`pam_env` module](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pam_env.8.html) reads a file very much like your `.env`.

[On Linux](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html), `pam_env` reads a system file `/etc/environment` and a user file `~/.pam_environment`. [On OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pam_env.8.html) (and other *BSD, which likewise use OpenPAM), it appears that `pam_env` only reads the system file, so you can't set variables per user this way, only for all users.

Comment: `~/.pam_environment` is no longer read [as of PAM 1.4](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/releases/tag/v1.4.0).

Answer (score 5):

Just create a function in $HOME/.config/fish/functions/env.fish with content:

```
for f in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
    sh $f
end
```

shared all vars created in bash in folder /etc/profile.d

for example: /etc/profile.d/golang.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$HOME/gobin

export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOBIN
```

just login on fish or bash, do `echo $GOPATH $GOROOT $GOBIN $PATH` and see the magic :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a file where you will store all your environment variables, named for example `~/.config/env_variables`. In this file, add `export` lines, like this:

```bash
# This file is meant to compatible with multiple shells, including:
# bash, zsh and fish. For this reason, use this syntax:
#    export VARNAME=value

export EDITOR=vim
export LESS="-M"
export GOPATH="$HOME/.local/share/gopath/"
export PATH="$PATH:/custom/bin/"
```

In your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file, include:

```
source ~/.config/env_variables
```

In your `~/.bashrc` file, include:

```
source ~/.config/env_variables
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @ridiculous_fish's answer, with the following function for bash it also works for arrays that contain spaces, such as `$PATH` if you have spaces in your paths. However `setenv` is already defined as a function in the fish standard library nowadays so I changed the name here to `shenv`

```bash
function shenv { 
        var="$1"
        shift
        export "$var=$(printf "%s\n" "$@" | paste -s -d: -)"
}
. ~/.env
```

Now in your `.env` file you can specify array components as separate arguments to the `setenv` command:

```
shenv PATH /my/path /my/path\ with\ spaces "/my/quoted path" $PATH
```

For fish @ridiculous_fish's simple implementation will do:

```fish
function shenv; set -gx $argv; end
source ~/.env
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind fork another process, then:

`env $(cat ~/.env) fish`

I use this way to share the same `.env` file with multiple shells in multiple projects. The syntax is easy, and it is quite flexible since you can `exit` the shell to regain your original environment.

More example:

`env $(cat .env) bash`

`env $(cat .env) zsh`

`env $(cat .env) sh`

One drawback is that it assumes `.env` only in `VAR=value` syntax (no comment, newline, or quotes).

I prefer to keep `.env` as simple as possible by naming variables more sensemaking instead of writing lots of comments and newlines. However, if there are some cases that comments and newlines cannot be avoided, it can still be easily solved by piping output to `grep`, `sed` or `awk`.

Sorry, my solution may not solve the original question because of the syntax of `.env`, but I did found it useful for sharing the same `.env` with different shells. Hope it can help anyone of you :)

Comment: I guess you mean `env $(cat ~/.env) fish`?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', the command substitution syntax in `fish` is with `(cmd)`; `$(cmd)` is the POSIX syntax.

Comment: That assumes `~/.env` online contains lines in `VAR=value` syntax (no comment, no `VAR="value"`, no empty lines...)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: OK, but, since the answer is giving a command to start a `fish`, I assumed that it was meant to be run from bash. Perhaps the answer is what Jian meant, but, if he meant “start a ``fish`` process, and then use this command to start another ``fish`` process”, I believe he should clarify.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: And your second comment would be clearer if you said “values cannot contain space character(s), whether quoted/escaped or not.”   And I don’t see a problem with empty lines.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' `fish`'s command substitution gets you one argument per line, empty or not (unless `$IFS` is unset, set to an empty list or list with one empty element), so empty lines will break it and spaces (as in `VAR=my value`) are not a problem. while POSIX substitution splits on `$IFS` and does globbing, so in POSIX syntax, you'd need something like `IFS=$NL; set -o noglob; env $(cat ~/.env) fish` to have something equivalent (which does remove empty lines though).

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' @StéphaneChazelas I am a `fish` user, so `env (cat ~/.env) fish` is what I would usually do, but I found that using `$()` would be less confusing as an answer. Thanks for the comments :)